# In PySpark, how to hash a string-type ID and turn it into a integer which is less than 365?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to find a function or a ufd to use which is equivalent to Ora_hash in Oracle. 
The purpose is to hash StringType ID and then changed it to a integer inside a range like (1,365).

eg. sha2(empolyeeid) and convert it into an integer that less than 365.  Or something similar. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use any hash algorithm you like and modulo 365

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is very helpful. (int(hashlib.sha256(s.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(), 16) % 10**8) % 365 fixed the problem.